iOS Bundling failed 14746ms (index.js) Unable to resolve "make-plural" from "node_modules/i18n-js/dist/require/Pluralization.js"
I am using React Native EXPO.
I am encountering the following error and need help to resolve it:
iOS Bundling failed 14746ms (index.js) Unable to resolve "make-plural" from "node_modules/i18n-js/dist/require/Pluralization.js"

I followed the Expo documentation to install expo-localization and i18n-js, and imported them in my App.js as follows:
import * as Localization from 'expo-localization';
import I18n from 'i18n-js';

However, I am still getting the above error during the build process.

metro.config.js
add 'mjs' to sourceExts.
const { getDefaultConfig } = require('@expo/metro-config')
const path = require('path')
const exclusionList = require('metro-config/src/defaults/exclusionList')

const extraNodeModules = {
  shared: path.resolve(__dirname + '/../shared')
}

const watchFolders = [
  path.resolve(__dirname + '/../shared')
]

const defaultConfig = getDefaultConfig(__dirname)

const config = {
  ...defaultConfig,
  transformer: {
    ...defaultConfig.transformer,
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: false
      }
    })
  },
  resolver: {
    ...defaultConfig.resolver,
    sourceExts: ['jsx', 'js', 'ts', 'tsx', 'cjs', 'json', 'mjs'],
    blockList: exclusionList([/#current-cloud-backend\/.*/]),
    extraNodeModules
  },
  watchFolders
}

module.exports = config


